# ggplot2 legend not appearing

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-bar

I'm having trouble producing a legend for my ggplot2 figure of categorical point data with a bar indicating the mean overlaid on top.

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(tree, o18)) 
plot + geom_point() +
    geom_crossbar(data=df2,aes(x=tree,ymin=o18, ymax=o18,y=o18,group=tree), width = 0.5)
```

where df is in the format:

| tree | o18 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 15 |
| A | 22 |
| B | 20 |
| B | 19.5 |
| C | 15 |
| D | 30 |

and df2 contains the means for each tree category:

| tree | o18 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 19 |
| B | 19.75 |
| C | 15 |
| D | 30 |

(data simplified)

My output looks like this: [image]

I would like to add a legend to the figure indicating that the points are the o18 values and the lines are the means for each category. However, I can't figure out how to do this. Is there any way to add such a legend in ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put something in `aes` for it to appear in the figure legend.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(tree, o18)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = "")) +
  geom_crossbar(data=df2,aes(x=tree,ymin=o18, ymax=o18,y=o18,group=tree, linetype = ""), width = 0.5) +
  labs(size = "o18 value", linetype = "mean")
```

[image: figure_with_legend]

Answer (score 1):

The @benson23 answer is correct, if you want more control you can use manual scales for different aesthetics. If you use `linetype` in `aes` instead of `fill`, you will get a legend as above, if you like that more.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~ tree,   ~ o18,
  "A",  15,
  "A",  22,
  "B",  20,
  "B",  19.5,
  "C",  15,
  "D",  30
)

df2 <- tribble(
  ~ tree,   ~ o18,
  "A",  19,
  "B",  19.75,
  "C",  15,
  "D",  30
)

shapes <- c("o18 values" = 16)
fills <- c("Means" = "black")

ggplot(df, aes(tree, o18)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = "o18 values")) +
  geom_crossbar(data=df2,aes(x=tree,ymin=o18, ymax=o18,y=o18,group=tree, fill = "Means"), width = 0.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes, name = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = fills, name = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>